# Python Regular Expression Ignoring a number that follows an *

Tags: python, regex

I want to retrieve all numbers excluding those that follows an `*` using regular expressions and those enclosed in either square brackets or parentheses.

Example:

```
8759*\[0-9](A|B)\*9*
```

Result:

```
[8,7,5]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Why are `0` and `9` not included? They are part of `[0-9]` and are not followed by `*`.

Comment: Because I want to read them as separate set of characters. I forgot to include that I want them to be ignored as well.

Comment: Show us some samples of things that should match and things that should not match. Without that, there's not much chance we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Numbers inside the square brackets and parenthesis are excluded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match pairs of square brackets and parentheses in alternation first before matching a digit with a negative lookahead that avoid matching a following `*`:

```
[i for i in re.findall(r'\[[^]]*]|\([^)]*\)|(\d)(?!\*)', '8759*\[0-9](A|B)\*9*') if i]
```

This returns:

```
['8', '7', '5']
```

Comment: The numbers 8759 could be changed and it should not be static.

Comment: If you look closely, the regex itself is `\[[^]]*]|\([^)]*\)|(\d)(?!\*)`, while `'8759*\[0-9](A|B)\*9*'` is simply the test string in the second argument to `re.findall`. You can replace that with a variable or any other string you want to test against.